# how to install two development environments

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

how to install two development environments with different versions of Django and Python

Currently, I use the development server and I installed `python 2.7.1` and `Django 1.4`

with the PATH environment variable

```
C:\Python27;C:\ Python27\Scripts
```

I use **virtualenv**

I installed the modules of the project with the command :

```
pip install-r requirements.txt
```

how to have two projects A and B ?

```
A: Python 2.7.1 and Django 1.4

B: Python 2.7.5 and Django 1.6
```

Comment: Just make two environments `mkvirtualenv project_a` and `mkvirtualenv project_b`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv). I've used it for a few projects and it works really well.

If you didn't want to use another tool, simply create a different `virtualenv` for each project as limelights suggested.